# pass form input to api url angular

Tags: angular, forms

I'm trying to pass data from input fields to an api url but it seems like I'm not doing it right.it passes the input to the api minus the form inputs. How can I pass the input to the api correctly? Here is my code:

component:

```
export class AppComponent {
 constructor(private http: Http) { }
age = ''
phone = ''
sex = ''
number = ''
amount = ''
email = ''
names = ''
  sendDetails(){
    this.http.get('http://example.api.com/step1.php?'+'age=this.age&phone=this.phone&sex=this.sex&number=this.number&amount=this.amount&email=this.email&names=this.names')
    .subscribe(value => {
      const submit = value
      console.log(submit);

    })

  }
}
```

HTML

```
<input type="text" [(ngModel)]=age >
<input type="text" [(ngModel)]=phone >
<input type="text" [(ngModel)]=sex >
<input type="text" [(ngModel)]=number >
<input type="text" [(ngModel)]=amount >
<input type="text" [(ngModel)]=email >
<input type="text" [(ngModel)]=names >
<button (click)=sendDetails()> submit</button>
```

Comment: You don't have any interpolation there, you're literally passing e.g. `'this.name'` as the query parameter for `age`.

Comment: That's not necessarily a problem, but you're showing something that makes no sense. Give a real [mcve] that demonstrates the *specific problem* with what you have. Is the API really expecting everything as query parameters?

Comment: @jonrsharpe as I said. I don't knoe how to pass parameters to the url directly from the input fields

Comment: Your question is unanswerable without more information about the server that's receiving the request; is it expecting query parameters? JSON? A URL-encoded form body? There isn't just one way *"to pass parameters to the URL"*, and it's unclear which specific part you're stuck on. Are you managing to make an actual request? Are you getting a response? If there are errors, where from and what do they say?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are passing exactly the string 'this.name' etc...
If  your API is ok then you need to write `+this.yourParameter+`
IE:

`this.http.get('http://example.api.com/step1.php?age='+this.age+'&phone='+this.phone+'&sex='+this.sex+'&number='+this.number+'&amount='+this.amount+'&email='+this.email+'&names='+this.names)`

Answer (score 1):

Swap:

```
'http://example.api.com/step1.php?'+'age=this.age&phone=this.phone&sex=this.sex&number=this.number&amount=this.amount&email=this.email&names=this.names'
```

For:

```
`http://example.api.com/step1.php?age=${this.age}&phone=${this.phone}&sex=${this.sex}&number=${this.number}&amount={this.amount}&email=${this.email}&names=${this.names}`
```

This is a very clean method and easy to work with when you need to concatenate values.